# Set products back to use default store values

Tags: import, store-view, csv

I've imported multiple products with dataflow-profiles. By mistake the products are added to store X. I want my products to use the default values instead of store X's. How do I mass set my products to use default values and images, and not the store specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with Magento built-in functions.
The fastest option is to drop the store and recreate it, you have to check if you can loose store related information.

Otherwise, if you have more Magento skills, you can directly remove the database entries in the EAV tables or write a script to do programmatically reset products.

Comment: I used SQL to solve my issues: 

DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_* WHERE store_id = %STOREID%;

Comment: Yep, you applied the second option of my post